# New Core Data in Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3

New Swift 3 presents replacements for types with prefix "NS" with types "NS"less. One of them - `NSData` becomes Data. So I see that in Core Data, type "Binary Data" equals to type `NSData`. So for example if my struct has var with "Data" type, I has to make it `NSData`.

Questions:

1) Am I right?

2) How to make NSData to be Data. When I do this:

`var photoData = Data(dataForTable[0].userPhoto)`,

I receive this: Cannot subscript a value of type "inout Array"

Comment: Nobody – except you  – knows what the type and contents of `dataForTable` and `userPhoto` is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as Data` to bridge an `NSData` instance to `Data`.